# Find email adresses in excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet which containts an emails in exact one column(the order of the column is not exact and changing).

I used the find function looking like this.

```
Sub emialy()

Cells.Find ("@",,xlValues,xlPart,xlByRows,,,,) ActiveCell.Copy 

End Sub
```

but I am recieving an error...

Then if a program finds where the emails list are beginning i want to copy that very first email and open an email client (outlook), create an new email and paste the exact copied email to the "to:" row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to use the `Find` function, is by setting a `Range` type variable to the result. This way you can trap the scenario `Find` was unable to find `@` throughout your worksheet's Cells with `If Not EmailRng Is Nothing Then`.

**Code**

```
Sub emialy()

Dim EmailRng As Range

Set EmailRng = Cells.Find(What:="@", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)    
If Not EmailRng Is Nothing Then ' succesful find
    EmailRng.Copy
Else
    MsgBox "Could not find the @ symbol"
End If

End Sub
```